# Open Source 3D scanning

Tags: 3d-design, open-source, scanning

I am trying to make a structured light 3D scanner using single camera, light projector and a turntable.

After days on Google I did not find any reliable open source project which I can get to work.  [SLStudio](https://github.com/jakobwilm/slstudio) really seemed a good choice but did not compile properly.

I was wondering if anyone knows a good open source which they have used with the same kind of setup? Any help would be really appreciated. I am blocked here.

Comment: In this video I've seen something, but I'm not sure if it's the source of open source https://youtu.be/_LyuTwJ2vsY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some really useful resources here but I got rid of structured light approach because of lesser resources.

I used [VisualSFM(.exe)](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/) , [VisualSFM(source)](https://github.com/mrquincle/visualsfm) with the turntable for the purpose and got some pretty neat results. Works well and easy to use.

Answer (score 12):

I did find only one 3d scanner which uses structured light. There is many projects using a laser diode. And these systems are completely opensource.

## Structured Light

### Structured Light 3D Scanning by kylemcdonald

- http://www.instructables.com/id/Structured-Light-3D-Scanning/?ALLSTEPS

[image]

## Laser diode

### Sardauscan

- http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-30-laser/?ALLSTEPS
- https://github.com/Sardau/Sardauscan
- http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:702470

[image]

### ATLAS 3D Scanner

- http://www.freelss.org
- http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1280901
- https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1545315380/atlas-3d-the-3d-scanner-you-print-and-build-yourse/posts/1475722

[image]

### Ciclop

- http://diwo.bq.com/en/tag/ciclop/
- https://github.com/bqlabs/ciclop

[image]

### 3D(ollar) Scanner

- https://hackaday.io/project/2021-3dollar-scanner
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Lets-cook-3D-scanner-based-on-Arduino-and-Proces/?ALLSTEPS

[image]

### "Super Make Something" Tutorial On How To Build a Simple 3D Scanner

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qeD2__yK4c
- http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1413891
- http://diy3dprinting.blogspot.de/2016/04/super-make-something-tutorial-on-how-to.html

[image]

## Different method

### $15 3D scanner consists of a tub of milk and a smartphone

Interesting idea of using milk and phone.

- http://www.instructables.com/id/GotMesh-the-Most-Cheap-and-Simplistic-3D-Scanner/
- http://www.3ders.org/articles/20160423-this-3d-scanner-consists-of-a-tub-of-milk-and-a-smartphone.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have also been looking for some free or paid software for doing 3D scanning and the closest I have found to something that might work is thishttp://wedidstuff.heavyimage.com/index.php/2013/07/12/open-source-photogrammetry-workflow/
But it isn't Structure from light (doesn't use a projector)

If you want to stick with Structured Light then I would suggest looking into openCV (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d90/group__structured__light.html#gsc.tab=0) I havn't looked into this much but it looks like you might be able to get something working with it.

Comment: Thanks user802599, OpenCV solution looks good, wish I had it earlier, will look into it anyway as i have worked with openCV

I got rid of structured light approach because there weren't enough resources and made one using VisualSFM. its really good and fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Kinect sensor for Xbox 360 OR Kinect sensor for Xbox One. That sensor allows you to get a true 3D surface with its SDK. You can connect these devices directly to your PC using USB (I have one).

Even the Xbox One model, in its SDK, has an example that allows you export your captured mesh as STL files.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Brown University School of Engineering: Projector-Camera Calibration / 3D Scanning Software](http://mesh.brown.edu/calibration/software.html).

I have not tried it myself, but give it a look.

Comment: I have given it a try.... didnt seem to work then... ill work on it again and get back to you.. thnx :)

Comment: @hamza I just wonder why you arent donate the answer with a +1 ? It actually gave you worth

Comment: I definitely will.... sorry that i didnt earlier..... :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not structured light. This uses a laser:

https://hci.rwth-aachen.de/fabscan

But it is completely open source software / open source hardware.

See also here:

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:14198

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBueeqDJ6rQ

Comment: Thanks Lars, seem like really good resources, ill look into each of them...

I got rid of structured light approach because there weren't enough resources and made one using VisualSFM. its really good and fast.

Answer (score -3):

[BQ Ciclop 3D Scanner](http://www.makeralot.com/ciclop-3d-scanner-diy-kit-p196/)

- Scan Volume: Bigger than 5 cm x 5 cm and smaller than 20 cm x 20 cm
- Scanning Precision: 0.5 mm

All the necessary parts for Ciclop are included in this DIY kit, which comes unassembled.

This Ciclop 3D Scanner Parts List:

- 1 x Plastic parts( 1 set with 11 pcs)
- 1 x Arduino Uno R3 with USB cable
- 1 x ZUM Scan Shield
- 1 x A4988 Stepper Driver
- 1 x C270 HD camera
- 1 x Nema17 stepper motor
- 2 x Laser
- 1 x Power supply adapter
- 1 x 16014 ball bearing
- 1 x M8 threaded rod (9 pcs)
- 2 x Acrylic panel
- 1 x 8mm spiral wrapping band
- 1 x Set of screw and nuts

Comment: Note to mods and reviewers: Whilst this is technically spam, it is *rather* descriptive and not malicious spam (unlike the two deleted answers). The info actually supplements one of the options given in [Amra's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/1221/4762). For this reason, it has currently be left in place. Maybe the link should be removed, and user account destroyed.